# How do you prevent horizontal interfearing of JS movement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a school project, we have just started learning JavaScript. I have to make a script that makes something move with JS. Well, I made the following script:

```
var object = document.getElementById("object");
        var omhoog = document.getElementById("omhoog");
        var omlaag = document.getElementById("omlaag");
        var links = document.getElementById("links");
        var rechts = document.getElementById("rechts");

        object.style.left = '0px';
        object.style.top = '0px';

        omlaag.onclick = function()
        {
            var positiehuidigtop = parseInt(object.style.top);
            setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.top)<positiehuidigtop+100)
                {
                    object.style.top = (parseInt(object.style.top) + 10) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }

        links.onclick = function()
        {
            var positiehuidigleft = parseInt(object.style.left);
            setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.left)>positiehuidigleft-100)
                {
                    object.style.left = (parseInt(object.style.left) - 10) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }

        rechts.onclick = function()
        {
            var positiehuidigleft = parseInt(object.style.left);
            setInterval(function()
            {
                if (parseInt(object.style.left)<positiehuidigleft+100)
                {
                    object.style.left = (parseInt(object.style.left) + 10) + 'px';
                }
            }, 10);
        }
```

Sorry for the Dutch stuff in there, but it's variables, so the name doesn't really matter.

Anyways, at first I just had the part of the script that made the div move right. Worked like a charm. But when I started adding left, it would interfear. Both directions are sort of fighting.

I really don't know what to do and this stuff is getting my a headache :/

Comment: It sounds like you need help in stopping one animation while starting another.  Is that correct?  Also, jQuery has a lot of functionality built-in that can help you.

Comment: Maybe school wants you to learn the native JS way, otherwise you might want to read about [**CSS3 animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) and [**jQuery animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Well, we just started programming. We have learned HTML and CSS so far. They let us do something with JS, just so we know the language. We will do PHP and jQuery next few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `clearInterval` to stop the already running interval timer before starting the new one.

```
var currentInterval;

omlaag.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(currentInterval);
    currentInterval = setInterval(
        ...
    );
};

rechts.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(currentInterval);
    currentInterval = setInterval(
        ...
    );
};
```

Comment: You should provide an example of how to do that.